# Parameter constraints - call method to check type in constraint?

Tags: c#, generics

I have a method with a generic parameter:

```
internal void DoSomething<T>(T workWithThis)
{
}
```

I now want to constrain this method to only accept parameters which inherit one of a few interfaces I'd like to specify. However I have not yet found a way to it. What I'd like looks like this:

```
internal void DoSomething<T>(T workWithThis) where T : ISomething | ISomethingElse
{
}
```

Obviously this is not working, so I tried it with a static method to check the Type of T:

```
public static bool CheckType(Type t)
{
return */check here*/
}

internal void DoSomething<T>(T workWithThis) where T : CheckType(typeof(T))
{
}
```

Obviously this is not going to work either. The question is why? Why is the compiler preventing me from doing that, based on my understanding there is no reason for it not to work

Answer (score 5):

> Why is the compiler preventing me from doing that, based on my understanding there is no reason for it not to work

The compiler is preventing you from doing it because you're trying to do something which isn't supported by C# as a language. The syntax you're trying to use does not comply with the productions in section 10.1.5 of the C# spec.

C# as a language simply does not support the scenario you require.

Now as for *why* the language doesn't allow this sort of flexibility - that comes down to the normal balancing act of:

- How many developers would benefit from this and how much
- Extra burden on other developers to understand a more complicated language
- Resources (primarily within Microsoft) required to design the language feature, implement and test it

Oh, and of course this isn't just C# - the CLR would have to support such a restriction as well, and it would at least encourage other CLR languages to understand it too.

I suggest you solve this by having two separate methods. Note that they can't just be overloads of generic methods, as overloads cannot differ only by generic type constraints. If you don't mind about boxing for value types implementing the interface, you *could* overload with:

```
internal void DoSomething(ISomething something)
{
}

internal void DoSomething(ISomethingElse somethingElse)
{
}
```

... although then if you pass in a value where the expression is a type implementing *both* interfaces, you'll end up with overload ambiguity.

Alternatively, just give the two methods different names.

Comment: yes of course thats the easiest solution ;) I just wanted to avoid generating 7 overloads of the same method in my case and was looking for a more 'elegant' way to do this

Comment: @buddybubble: Having 7 overloads would *usually* suggest that the design could be improved to start with, e.g. having a single interface that all of these other interfaces extend. It's hard to say more without having more context, but you need to accept that C# just doesn't support type parameter constraints of "one of these interfaces".

Answer (score 2):

The compiler has to verify all the constraints at compile time, and cannot call a method to do so.

The only things you can specify in the `where` constraints are:

- `new()` - require a parameterless constructor
- `class` - must be a reference type
- `struct` - must be a value type
- `SomeBaseClass`
- `ISomeInterface`
- `T : U` - must be, inherit from, or implement one of the other generic parameters

See the [C# Programming Guide - Constraints on Type Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) for more information.

As for why, you should never have to answer "I see no reason for this to work". You have to start in the opposite direction, "Why should this work", and then come up with enough plausible and realistic scenarios and requirements to make it worthwhile to implement.  See [Minus 100 Points](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericgu/archive/2004/01/12/57985.aspx) by Eric Gunnerson.

To fix this in your code, you should derive both interfaces from a common interface, and add a constraint on that instead.

If the two interfaces have nothing in common, then I question the benefit of actually adding a constraint in the first place.

For instance, if your code is going to call a method on the objects being used with the generic type/method, then obviously both interfaces have to have the same notion about what that method is, and the only way to do that would be for the method to be defined in a common base interface. That the two interfaces happen to have the same method or property declared, with the same signature, does not make it the same method.

Having said that, are you sure you even *need* generics here?

How about just declaring two methods, each taking one such interface?

```
internal void DoSomething(ISomething workWithThis)
internal void DoSomething(ISomethingElse workWithThis)
```

Comment: I know the guide. If I specify a static method that checks if T is one of a given set of interfaces, based on my understanding, all necessary informations should be available at compile time

Comment: @buddybubble - there's no restriction that static methods aren't able to obtain access to global runtime state information - information *not* available at compile time.

Comment: But the spec does not allow the compiler to call a yet-to-be-compiled method. This is such a corner-case that it isn't worth the time to get this right or usable. Please note that there is no way for the compiler to call any such code at compile-time at all, anywhere. As such, this would be the first (or one of) place to have that kind of support and you need to weigh that up against the benefits. To fix this, however, derive both interfaces from a common interface and constrain on that instead.

Comment: I don't really _need_ generics in this case. I wanted to avoid creating 7 overloads of the same method (to add a mocked property) and thought this would be a nice way of doing this

Answer (score 1):

The compiler uses the generic constraint to determine what operations is available on T within the generic method - so allowing an or expression would not be type safe. For example you have two interfaces `IFirst` and `ISecond`:

```
public interface IFirst
{
    void First();
}

public interface ISecond
{
    void Second();
}
internal void DoSomething<T>(T workWithThis) where T : IFirst or ISecond
{
    //How to call this method if the type is ISecond
    workWithThis.First();
    //How to call this method if the type is IFirst
    workWithThis.Second();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define an empty interface that holds all of them.

Remember, that in `C#` interfaces *can* have multiple inheritance.

For example:

```
public interface IHolder : ISomething, ISomethingElse 
{

}
```

and for generic

```
internal void DoSomething<T>(T workWithThis) where T : IHolder
{
}
```

Comment: yes thought of that as well, but unfortunately that is not an option in my case. Interface definitions are scattered across multiple solutions and changing inheritance across the entire project is not an option

Comment: @buddybubble: yo are not *changing*, you are defining a new one, and you can define it only inside assembly that *actually needs* that.

Comment: are you sure this is going to work? would T == ISomethingElse always equal T == IHolder? I thought T would have to implement both ISomething AND ISomethingElse to implicitly implement IHolder

Comment: @buddybubble: it depends on *how* you manage code inside your program. If you have somewhere already defined object of type ISomething you can use this function, the same is for ISomethingElse.